# Unwanted p and br tags in ckeditor

Tags: php, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I am using ckeditor for writing articles for my website. The problem is when I add a a space within an article i get something like the following:

```
<p></p><br />
```

Can anyone help me with how to configure ckeditor such that when I press enter with the attempt to add a paragraph, I actually get a paragraph and and not the line i posted on top. As a result I am getting one paragraph and I have to go o the database to put the br tag inside the p tags for me to actually get a space to separate the paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I press enter with the attempt to add a paragraph, I actually get a paragraph and and not the line i posted on top.

But by default you **actually** get a paragraph. For example if you press enter in this situation (`^` represents selection):

```
<p>foo^</p>
```

You will get:

```
<p>foo</p>
<p>^<br /></p>
```

The `<br>` inside the empty paragraph is called a bogus `<br>` or filler `<br>` and it must be there, otherwise the block will be 0px high.

So I truly don't understand your question and I advise you to check your configuration, because **by default CKEditor produces paragraphs**.

PS. Setting `config.enterMode` to `CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR` is not recommended. Editor works best with `ENTER_P` which is the default setting. If you don't like spacing between paragraphs just edit the `contents.css` file and add a rule there which removes margins around block elements like `p`, `h1`, etc. Remember to clear cache after doing so. Read more here: [Enter Key Configuration](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_enterkey).

Comment: i understand what you are saying, but what then is the fix to the problem because it gives me an extra space i do not want. At the moment i changed to CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR but am actually worried since i have been reading all over that its not reccommended.

Comment: I updated my answer (the last two sentences). These margins are added by the default stylesheet (or the browser) - you can remove them there with a basic CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in order to get just a `<br>` tag.

This functionality is also 100% configurable.

[Demo](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/plugins/enterkey/enterkey.html)

Comment: Thank you for the guide. I will play around with ENTERMODE and see if i can get the desirable result

Comment: @Tatenda You are welcome. In the past I have read that altering the functionality of EnterMode is not a good idea. There are plugins which might rely on the default functionality and changing EnterMode would break those plugins. I would personally advise that you should get used to pressing Shift+Enter. Good luck!

Comment: the SHIFT+ENTER works well thank you. But the problem is now that move actually inserts 2 br tags. Do you happen to know about this?

Comment: @Tatenda I am not sure, the demo on the website only does one `<br>` tag. Are you using the latest version of CKEditor? Has is it been modified in any way? Try toggling the Source button to see exactly what CKEditor is doing. It is possible that your PHP is adding additional `<br>` tags.

Comment: I suppose its PHP adding additional br tags because when I inspect the source it looks different from what is actually stored in the database. The source has the right amount of br tags but in the database i see double the number of tags and also when the article is rendered for the user to read it has double the number of spaces

Comment: @Tatenda If your PHP is using `nl2br();` then it would cause your data to have more `<br>`'s that you want.